# Turn off auto committing in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I’m looking for an option to explicitly commit/rollback every query executed in SSMS without the need to start the transaction explicitly. By default SSMS auto commits leaving no option to rollback.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can SET [IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-implicit-transactions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) in a query window.

If you set this in the `Query/Query Options` menu it will be set just for the current query.  If you set this in the `Tools/Options/Query Execution/SQL Server/ANSI` menu it will be the default for all new queries.

[image]

Comment: I want to just open a new query windows and to have an explicit transaction started

Comment: See above edit.  Technically in IMPLICIT TRANSACTIONS a new transaction is not started until the first DML/DDL statement that requires it.

Comment: Thank god, i've changed the configurations a wile a go and forgot how to rollback it