# Securing SQL Query with Transaction SSMS

Tags: sql-server

I have this long query where I drop, create database and tables, make relations, insert data and create stored procedures, all hard coded and I was wondering how I can secure everything in case the user presses F5 by mistake. For example, could I place the whole query inside a transaction statement?

Comment: The CREATE DATABASE statement must run in autocommit mode (the default transaction management mode) and is not allowed in an explicit or implicit transaction.

Comment: Adding to what @sepupic said, other DDL/DML can be placed in a transaction so that it can be committed or rolled back as an atomic operation. However, not sure how that would help since a COMMIT at the end of the script would execute whether the script was run intentionally or not.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off auto-commit in SSMS can partially achieve your purpose (as explained by sepupic, turn off auto-commit doesn't work for CREATE DATABASE statement), refer to: [Turn off auto committing in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50542896/turn-off-auto-committing-in-sql-server-management-studio-ssms)