COMMIT TRAN not working in SQL Server 2019
I am working in an environment where I run the code below and SSMS says that the command was executed successfully. However, when I try to close the window it says that I have uncommitted transactions. This makes no sense to me. The transaction that I defined should have been committed to the DB using the COMMIT TRAN line. Why didn't this work?
I see in another question here on stack overflow that I could try changing my server settings to explicit transactions instead of implicit, but why should I do this when my code clearly has a BEGIN TRAN and a COMMIT TRAN? What is the recommended approach to this situation?
Update: I added print statements to try to see what's going on and it looks like the UPDATE starts its own transaction. It would be weird as heck to write 2 COMMIT TRANs. Did something change with SQL Server 2019 or SSMS that this is now happening? I don't remember having to do double COMMIT TRAN back in the day.
The code:
set xact_abort on
print '1 @@Trancount: ' + cast(coalesce(@@trancount, 0) as nvarchar(100))
begin try
print '2 @@Trancount: ' + cast(coalesce(@@trancount, 0) as nvarchar(100))
begin tran
print '3 @@Trancount: ' + cast(coalesce(@@trancount, 0) as nvarchar(100))
update [Production Order]
set [SO Number] = '0063420', [SO Line Item] = '', Parent = '553306000'
where [PrO Number] = '553306001'
print '4 @@Trancount: ' + cast(coalesce(@@trancount, 0) as nvarchar(100))
commit tran
print '5 @@Trancount: ' + cast(coalesce(@@trancount, 0) as nvarchar(100))
end try
begin catch
    print '6 @@Trancount: ' + cast(coalesce(@@trancount, 0) as nvarchar(100))
    rollback tran
    print '7 @@Trancount: ' + cast(coalesce(@@trancount, 0) as nvarchar(100))
    select ERROR_MESSAGE()
end catch
print '8 @@Trancount: ' + cast(coalesce(@@trancount, 0) as nvarchar(100))

Output:
1 @@Trancount: 0
2 @@Trancount: 0
3 @@Trancount: 1

(1 row affected)
4 @@Trancount: 2
5 @@Trancount: 1
8 @@Trancount: 1

Completion time: 2024-07-24T12:48:00.9458946-07:00


may be you have uncommitted transaction in other SSMS-window?

@Sergey nope. When I try to go to other windows and close them, the uncommitted transactions error doesn't appear.

If you ran the query without a commit or rollback, perhaps you accidently only had 'begin Tran' selected, and then ran it again with both and begin and commit or rollback you would have 1 open transaction remaining.

This usually happens if you're playing around with transactions. I suggest using SET XACT_ABORT ON as well

@siggemannen to this day I still don't fully understand set xact_abort on. Can you explain it in simpler terms what it does? Any why wouldn't this be on by default? If I get any kind of error in my code, I would not want to impact the database in any way

Strange results. I thought implicit transactions would only increment @@rowcount if it was zero. Probably still best to only issue a BEGIN TRANSACTION if implicit transactions are off.

sounds like you have some weird setting on ssms, perhaps autocommit off. Or there's some trigger, i dunno, this ain't normal. What happens if you change the update and add WHERE 1 = 0

There are cases when you don't want to automatically rollback everything in a proc. 2 examples that come to mind where I have used it... if you are using try/catch you normally handle rollback yourself as part of the try/catch pattern because it doesn't play well with automatic rolling back. Another example is when you use save points and only want to partially rollback. There is a database setting for it, but personally I always turn it on in a proc to be sure.

Are you using IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS? https://stackoverflow.com/a/50543011/14868997

I suspect implicit transactions will start a transaction with BEGIN TRY. You then start a nested transaction with BEGIN TRAN which increments @@TRANCOUNT. You then COMMIT which decrements @@TRANCOUNT so you need another COMMIT to decrement @@TRANCOUNT to zero and actually do a commit. I would alter the code to only do a BEGIN TRANSACTION with explicit transactions.
I cannot test this at the moment but try playing with:
SELECT @@TRANCOUNT;
begin try;
SELECT @@TRANCOUNT;
--IF @@OPTIONS & 2 = 0
    begin transaction;
SELECT @@TRANCOUNT;
update [Table]
set [Col1] = 'Val1', [Col2] = '', Col3 = '553306000'
where [ID] = '553306001';
commit;
SELECT @@TRANCOUNT;
commit;
SELECT @@TRANCOUNT;
end try;


What a wonderfully unmanageable mess would using begin try be if it worked that way. Fortunately, it does not. Whoever upvoted this answer is not doing a good service to anyone.

@TheMortiestMorty actually the site guidelines are quite clear, all voting, up and down, is deliberately anonymous and doesn't ever require a reason. The reasons are given when you mouse-over the up or down vote buttons. If someone wishes to explain their reason for voting they are of course welcome but there is no requirement or expectation to do so.

Just change "I suspect implicit transactions will start a transaction with BEGIN TRY" to "IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON will start a new transaction with any query or DML statement" the rest is correct. The real answer is to turn that option OFF.
